# ng-model-options ignored if it's a $scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am currently using the AngularJS Bootstrap Datepicker (also known as uib-datepicker). I am currently trying to set an UTC offset on it, which can be done by setting the ngModelOptions likewise: `ng-model-options="{timezone: '+02:00'}"` which works fine. However, if I set the ngModelOptions with a $scope variable, changes on timezone won't be made. So, to be clear, this works:

```
                    <input uib-datepicker-popup="{{picker.format}}"
                       ng-model="picker._value"
                       is-open="picker.opened"
                       datepicker-options="picker.options"
                       ng-model-options="{timezone: '+02:00'}"
                       close-text="{{'close' | translate}}"
                       clear-text="{{'clear' | translate}}"
                       current-text="{{'current' | translate}}"/>
```

But this doesn't:

```
                    <input uib-datepicker-popup="{{picker.format}}"
                       ng-model="picker._value"
                       is-open="picker.opened"
                       datepicker-options="picker.options"
                       ng-model-options="ngModelOptions"
                       close-text="{{'close' | translate}}"
                       clear-text="{{'clear' | translate}}"
                       current-text="{{'current' | translate}}"/>
```

Even though the "$scope.ngModelOptions" variable holds the exact same value "{timezone: '+02:00'}"

I am using angular-ui-bootstrap 2.5.6, and angularjs 1.6.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I quickly found the answer: the ngModelOptions actually has to be set in the "options" object of the datepicker, like so:

```
  const datePickerOptions = {
    opened: false,
    format: 'shortDate',
    options: {
      startingDay: $moment().startOf('week').isoWeekday(),
      minDate: null,
      maxDate: null,
      showWeeks: false,
      ngModelOptions: {
        timezone: '+02:00'
      }
    }
  };
```

In the bootstrap docs (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap), it says that ng-model-options is a supported angular options inside the uib-datepicker input, but somehow it doesn't work with a scope variable, so just set it in the datepicker-options.